# Hex to ASCII string conversion on the fly

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm

I am interested to know if there is a possibility to read the records of a table containing hexadecimal values and convert them on-the-fly into string datatype before displaying / using them as a results (like on the example picture, where the raw data is displayed on the left and how the program interprets it on the right portion).

*Data taken from MS Dynamics NAV v5 (SP1) ERP software...*

[image: SAMPLE SCREENSHOT]

Additionally, I would like to know if there is a possibility of setting a condition (e.g. where) that could be typed as a string (e.g. where *something* like 'OS%') and DBMS could convert it to hex and search for it in a table to narrow down the end results of a query.

Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: That isn't ASCII. The hex for M is 4D not B6

Comment: That looks like its some kind of proprietary binary format. There is ascii in there. The ID BRA-M02 is the 4252412D4D3032 part. But the rest is not "Machine Center:". You need the documentation for whatever this binary is coming from so that you can interpret it properly. For all you know, some of it could be binary coded decimal, some of it could be checksums, some of it could be length values, etc.

Comment: I suppose you are right, since when I try using RapidTables online HEX to ASCII converter I get as a "decoded" result seven gibberish characters, followed by **"BRA-M02"** and then three more weird characters ...

Comment: Maybe the first bytes relate to a dictionary of prefixes?

Comment: It could be very well so ... I would be happy if I could "get" only the document numbers out of the strings ... The one under line 10 is the most important one for me ... So if I could convert it from hex to ASCII and then "cut" the doc number from in between any prefixes and suffixes - that would be great!

Comment: Looks like this could explain it. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav/2009/08/06/how-do-record-links-encode-their-data-in-sql-server/

Comment: Whoa @MartinSmith! Nicely done ... For sure a great read. I will need a whole week ahead of me for this article to sink in, since I am a newbie at these HEX kind of things ...

Comment: I'm not sure if the article is for your specific version though. And the comments indicate that this is undocumented and changes between versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your information, that this column is from Microsoft Dynamics NAV it sounds really clear.

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh896055(v=nav.70).aspx) says this:

> Specifies the record that the link is attached to.
>
> The following syntax is used:
>
> `<table name>: <primary key1>, <primary key2>, <primary key3>`

I'm pretty sure, Microsoft has a combined schema for this value, which is a bit strange but well not that hard to fiddle out I think.

If you split your values up to the `FF`, you can see two results:

```
--0xB6A1E6050089FF4252412D4D3032000000
select convert(int,0xB6A1E6050089FF) -- Object_ID for the specified table
select convert(varchar(100),0x4252412D4D3032000000) -- Primary Key 1
```

You can try to take this further and execute this on your machine:

```
select object_name(convert(int,0xB6A1E6050089FF))
```

This should give you a valid table name. Hopefully. ;-)

I can't check this on my side, as I havent those system installed. If so, I can add a short command to this result to automate the splitting for you.

Your other string can be splitted like this:

```
--0x1E150000008B000000000089FF534F3030303133353532000087102700000000
SELECT convert(int,0x1E150000008B000000000089FF) -- 35327 (object_id)
SELECT convert(varchar(100),0x534F30303031333535320000) -- SO00013552
SELECT convert(int,0x87102700000000) -- 0
```

I think, you need to parse it dynamically. You should check the basetable (the first part). After that, check the primary keys in their ordering. After checking this, you can dynamically parse them into their target format. The only thing, which may be a bit harder, is the part of the splitting. Normally the first part should go until the `FF`. After that each part can be splitted by multiple zeros.

Comment: Hey! I tried it - and it is working to some degree ^_^ I need to further explore it in the morning (since it is getting very late in my time zone), but you guys gave me direction and a hope ... Just one more info, how do you know where exactly to split a hex string ... for example, how do I split this long one taken from the line 4 on the sample image I left above: 0x1E150000008B000000000089FF534F3030303133353532000087102700000000
Thank you a gazillion times! I will revert back as soon as I find something out ...

Comment: Maybe this can be splitted like the example above (I edited it).

Comment: I've added an example for the splitting too. By the way, my clock says 23:15. It's getting dark here too. ;-)

Comment: It worked! I've managed to get the desired result, the code behind it is not so neatly put together ... but it does the job. Here it is:  
  
SELECT TOP 1000
[Link ID],
[Record ID],
convert(varchar(100),SUBSTRING([Record ID],8,8)) as [Fixed Asset No]
FROM [MyDbName].[dbo].[Record Link]
where [Record ID] like '' + convert(varchar,0xE01500000089FF) + '%'
order by [link id]

Comment: Not the best implementation in my eyes, but anyway you have to deal with it. Nice to see that it helped you.

Comment: I can only imagine how my newbie code looks to a pro dev ... like some sort of scenario out of "Incredible Machines" game, fragile and delicate but yet it somehow works :). I tried converting the whole hex string by following the documentation @Martin Smith and you supplied, but the only part I got thrown off the path is converting little endian hex value of 0xE0150000 to int 5600 that represents the object id (table name)... The rest of the parts of HEX string is encoded in their correct binary representation.