# Converting binary data containing null (0x00) characters to ASCII in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

On SQL Server (2016+), I have data stored in a `varbinary` column, saved by some Java application, which contains a mixture of binary data and ASCII text. I want to search the column using a like operator or otherwise to look for certain ASCII strings, and then view the returned values as ASCII (so that I can read the surrounding text).

The data contains non-characters such as "00" (0x00), and these seem to stop SQL Server from converting the string as might otherwise be possible according to the answers at [Hex to ASCII string conversion on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295675/hex-to-ascii-string-conversion-on-the-fly) . In the example below, it can be seen that the byte "00" stops the parsing of the ASCII.

```
select convert(varchar(max),0x48454C4C004F205000455445,0) as v1       -- HELL
select convert(varchar(max),0x48454C4C4F205000455445,0) as v2         -- HELLO P
select convert(varchar(max),0x48454C4C4F2050455445,0) as v3           -- HELLO PETE
```

How can I have

```
 select convert(varchar(max), 0x48454C4C004F205000455445, 0)
```

...return something like this?:

```
HELL?O P?ETE
```

(Or, less ideally, have an expression similar to

```
convert(varchar(max), 0x48454C4C004F205000455445, 0) like '%HE%ETE%'
```

...return the row?)

It works on the website https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html with `48454C4C004F205000455445` as input.

[image]

I'm not overly concerned about performance, but I want to stay within SQL Server, and ideally within the scope of T-SQL which can be copied and pasted easily.

I've tried using replace on "00", but this could causes problems with characters ending with 0, as in "5000" in the examples above. There may be bytes other than 0x00 which cause string conversion to stop as well.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132996/convert-hexadecimal-to-varchar for an existing similar question - and possible anwers.

Comment: If you get `?` it means the data is **not** ASCII, or at least, it's not in the server's codepage. `?` is an **error** character returned when a conversion from one codepage to another fails. You're trying to fix an application bug (the bad storage format) after the fact, without even knowing what the data is - is it really mixed text and binary? Or is it an unfortunate attempt to store UTF8 as binary instead of using `nvarchar`? Did the application try to "fix" Unicode storage by breaking it?

Comment: `It works on the website` no, it doesn't. That site fails to convert those characters but doesn't emit the error character. The real fix would be to fix the application bug. Which SQL Server version are you using? 2019 added UTF8 as an encoding so *maybe* you decode that string. You won't be able to index or easily search that field even then

Comment: Yes, the data is pretty arbitrary mixture of non-ASCII and ASCII: that's the whole problem. I've tried nvarchar and UTF-8 conversions, but the resulting chinese makes less sense than the binary. The point is that I'm NOT EVEN GETTING ? characters: rather that the convert function seems to give up as soon as it meets 0x00.

Comment: It works on the website: yes it does. I don't care about the binary, I just want to see ALL of the ASCII, including that which is after the first 0x00. Try runing the v1 / v2 /v3 examples in SQL server and you'll get the idea.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing UTF8 for an arbitrary mixture? How did you try the conversion? SQL Server has very limited support for this. You'd have to use C# and eg `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)`.

Comment: Did the application try to normalise accents, replacing the normalised diacritics with `0x00` perhaps? You'll have to remove all `0x00` bytes from the string before converting. You should really get the application developers to fix this, or store the converted text separately. The conversion means that any query won't be able to. use any indexes and result in a full table scan and conversion, each time you try to search the data. At the very least, you should consider a trigger or persisted computed column that removes `0x00` and converts the bytes to text

Comment: I think it's somehting like a stringification (/binaryification) of a Java dictionary: e.g. I can see variable names in ASCII interspersed with gibberish which I presume to be binary and not UTF-8: in UTF-8, it makes no sense either, and there's no reason to think it's actual Chinese. I'd love to string up the application developers for sure, but even if  I did, existing installs would still have the problem, and so would I  :-(.

Comment: Re removing 0x00, that would be ideal. Doing a string replace doesn't work, as a preceding byte ending in 0 gets its second 0 chopped along with the first of 0x00. PErhaps if I could split the hex into an array of bytes, filter out the 0x00s, then reassemble the value? I don't know how to do this though.

Comment: If you want to search that data, you need to decode it and index it anyway. `0x00` isn't used in UTF8 except for the `NUL` character so this isn't UTF8, this is just bad text. Your conversion to `varchar` will also contain that `NUL` character, which isn't visible. You could try `REPLACE(converted,CHAR(0),'')` to remove the `NUL`s from the converted text

Comment: There's no second byte, `00` is a single byte

Comment: "here's no second byte" - sorry, I meant second byte of the stringified hex representation of the second half of actual binary byte. i.e. the sequence 0x50 0x09, when string replaced, becomes 0x59     --- actually that MIGHT be good enough. Will test.

Comment: What you posted is binary data, not stringified. Have you tried `REPLACE(convert(varchar(max), 0x48454C4C004F205000455445, 0),CHAR(0),'')` ?

Comment: That will fail because `0x00` is the string terminator in C/C++, so the conversion assumes the string ends at the first `0x00`. If it was anything else, eg `0x01`, the conversion would go on

Comment: So far, this looks workable, based on the heuristic that I don't care about corrupting bytes starting with zero in their hex representation, which aren't interesting in ASCII: `convert(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),REPLACE(convert(varchar(max), 0x48454C4C004F205000455445, 1),'00',''),1),0)` gives `HELLO PETE`

Comment: Can't you use `replace()` on binary data, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494778/how-to-perform-a-replace-on-varbinary-data-in-sql

Comment: I've tested the expression in my previous comment on actual data, and it seems to get to the end of the value. Some of the strings do contain UTF-8 which comes out with accents mangled, but thankfully I don't need to care about them.

Comment: Re replace on binary, `REPLACE(0x48454C4C004F205000455445,0x00,0x)` still gives me `HELL` only alas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the row (the more limited version of this question), a simple `like` operator on the value appears to work when run directly on the binary value, despite the intervening 0x00 values:

```
    0x48454C4C004F205000455445 like 'HE%ETE%'
```

In other words, `like` can cope where `convert` can't.

To view the actual value, the best I've managed so far is this:

```
convert(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),
  REPLACE(
    convert(varchar(max), 0x48454C4C004F205000455445, 1)
    ,'00',''
  )
,1),0)
```

This gives `HELLO PETE`, and works well enough on the actual data, getting to its end.

(It depends on the heuristic of not caring about converting e.g. 0x50 0x03 to 0x53 and similar, but I can live with that, as 0x0z, where z is 1 to f, represents control characters, which don't occur around the text I'm interested in).

(thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos for prodding me in a useful direction!)